# How to solve the short battery life with galaxy s4?

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I bought Galaxy S4 in just half year. However I found some wrong with the bettery, my phone shutdown automatically recently with over 20% battery. I can only use the phone for two hours after my phone charged full. How can I solve it? Should I change my bettery? Or some thing wrong the software?

Comment: Have you rooted,  have you disabled google location services? They do drain battery, but from what you say this would seem to be the hardware to be honest. Check the serial on your battery and if it begins with BD it is due a replacement from Samsung, due to defects. Check your phone sits level and the battery isn't swollen, this is another issue many S4s have at the moment. The best bet is a service centre, and see if you can get a free battery replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the warranty left it is best to change the battery , but the problem could be because of overcharging and discharging of the battery it has happened to a friend of mine who had a samsung galaxy s3 and after 3 months after purchase he had his battery replaced by warranty.the reason they gave was that he was using the charger on for too long and it had affected the battery.

personally it doesn't occur a lot but if it does its better to check it at a service center and get to know the problem clearly instead